# How can I map a field of a json form submit to a parameter directly in Spring Boot?

Tags: json, spring-boot

I'm submitting a JSON request to a form in Spring boot. It has one single parameter: isUp.

The post request sends

```
{isUp: true}
```

I would like to directly map the post request to a spring boot @PostMapping. If i submit the request as url params, ie

```
isUp=true
```

Then I can do that by having my method signature being:

```
 @PostMapping("/name/")
 public ResponseEntity method( @RequestParam boolean isUp) {
```

I would like to achieve the same result but while submitting the form as JSON.

I don't want to map it to a form, like what @RequestBody does. I just want to map the boolean.

Thanks!

Comment: Well , you have tow choises :
-1: You create a java object to receive your json in via requestBody
-2: You can send your json like a string rather than a boolan as you did in the example and you can exract it as you want in your back end